# Need setOnLoadCallback() Alternative

Tags: jquery, google-ajax-api

I'm working on an internal site, and cannot make an external call to Google's API to use their setOnLoadCallback() function, and can't seem to find any pure JQuery alternatives that I can use with my locally-called JQuery. For reference, here's the code I'm trying to implement, but the original developer wrote it using the Google API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");



  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { 

    var timeout = null;

    var initialMargin = parseInt($("#siteMenuBar").css("margin-top"));



    $("#siteMenuBar").hover(

        function() {

            if (timeout) {

                clearTimeout(timeout);

                timeout = null;

            }

            $(this).animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 'fast');

        },

        function() {

            var menuBar = $(this);

            timeout = setTimeout(function() {

                timeout = null;

                menuBar.animate({ marginTop: initialMargin }, 'slow');

            }, 1000);

        }

    );

  });

</script>
```

Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I think all you would need is replace

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: I ended up going another route with this, but thanks for taking the time to offer a suggestion - perhaps this will help others in a similar situation.